Simulate changing the GPS location associated with the Wi-Fi access point
I have a question regarding obtaining GPS coordinates through WiFi access points (AP) on an Android app.
As I understand it, Android apps can collect GPS locations through WiFi APs if granted the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions. The steps are as follows:
Step 1: The app collects the available WiFi APs in the vicinity, as shown in the figure.

Step 2: The app sends the information of these WiFi APs to the Google Location Service to retrieve the GPS information associated with the Access Points.
Step 3: The app receives the information returned from the Google Location Service.
Specifically, the Google Location Service has GPS information associated with WiFi APs because when a phone (GPS enabled) connects to a WiFi Access Point, it sends this information to the Google Location Service (cached). Therefore, the app can still know the location if another device connects to the same WiFi AP without enabling location services.
I have two questions regarding this issue:

Is the GPS information associated with WiFi APs sent to the Google Location Service stored at Google, locally, or both (locally and cloud)? I tried to get a list of Wifi access points and queries using Google Location Service API through Postman on my laptop. GPS results are still returned, as shown below.


Is there any way to update the GPS information associated with WiFi APs? For instance, I have a 1000m road and collect 10 GPS points (one point every 100m).  Can I update the GPS information associated with WiFi APs every 30 seconds, corresponding to each GPS point?
Thank you




Stored at Google with most probably a local cache 2) As seen in 1 and related reports 2 and 3 live cloud data takes a while to update. I am not aware of any third-party programmatic way to update Google's data, probably as they only trust data through what their systems collect.


@MorrisonChang I'm not sure if the GPS location associated with the WiFi access point is stored in the local cache or on the cloud or both. But I tried getting the access point list and query from POSTMAN (on laptop). Google Location Service API still returns results. But laptops don't have cache for this part. I have updated this description to the question.

Cloud definitely as WiFI AP location triangulation (i.e. in buildings) but may be assisted by AGPS from mobile towers. My assumption is that the public Google API has less detail, i.e. the approx. GPS coordinates of a WiFi AP,  than what is provided to Android Google Maps or on device Google Services. Otherwise others can scrape data. Feel free to experiment for clarity.

@MorrisonChang yes, Thank you.
